# How to get response headers and time using capybara-webkit

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

How to get response of seperate ajax requests in a web page using capybara-webkit?

Is there any particular method available to capture response time of each request?

Note:
Am using capybara with rspec.

For eg: i have 3 Ajax requests in a web page. I need to get separate response time of each request and the response time of entire web page.

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not possible since webserver is running in the different process but you could create a custom rack middle-ware and dump all responses to the separate log file. For the beginning you could implement technique described here: https://gist.github.com/2975611 and for dumping headers you could use some code snippets from http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/ContentLength.html